# Is it a "Bary center" or a "Bari center"?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, terminology, erratum

(*Studying Coordination Chemistry, "Crystal Field Theory" at school*)

Apparently, different sources spell this differently.

[The Wikipedia article on Crystal Field Stabilization Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory#Crystal_field_stabilization_energy), calls it the "Barycenter" (as does my school textbook)

> [image]

However, the *actual* [Wikipedia article on the "Barycenter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) refers to, (as far as I can tell) the center of mass of two mutually orbiting bodies. Whereas the "Bary/Baricenter" I'm talking about is the zero-energy reference level in octahedral complexes.

Another book I have at hand (*Concise Inorganic Chemistry* Lee, J.D), prominently uses the term "Bari centre".

---

The center/centre distinction aside, what I've been able to glean from my books (and the internet), is that this term is spelled in *four* different ways (Wah! Such gross inconsistency in literature!):

- Barycenter
- Bary center
- Baricenter
- Bari center

But which one's correct (or at least, a more preferred term in Chemistry-literature)?

Comment: "barycentre" is the original spelling of the word.  https://books.google.com/books?id=fIRAAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22Barycentre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9gIjfh_vXAhXkSN8KHaFpAcUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Barycentre%22&f=false so none of the above

Comment: My Greek roots say barycenter, though I'll allow DavePhD's variant.

Comment: @DavePhD +1 for insisting on th BE version. ;-) And Bari is a town in Italy. Looks to me like Lee tried to be original.

Comment: But [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77393/why-do-compounds-form-if-overall-energy-of-free-ion-increases-according-to-cft) it is written "bari"center :(.

Comment: @Nilay Yup, I saw that too. Judging from the other comments, apparently "barycentre" works (but I'll wait till someone posts an answer). O:)

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/barycentre , https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/barycentric , https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barycenter

Comment: @Karl Yep, it seems now that "barycenter/re" is the more widely used term; the question now, would be whether it applies to the Crystal Field Theory as well as two-body systems (the links suggest the latter). Thanks for the link! O:)

Comment: As far as I can tell Barycentre is the English spelling, Baricentre the French (and maybe Italian?). So maybe the version with an "i" is from francophones?

Comment: "bari" or "bary" are not English words, so the versions with two words are  just plain wrong.

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to say that Barycenter is the correct spelling for the sought word. The other versions are artifact of the original word as some authors preferred to name (especially in the internet).

Barycenter (or Barycentre in British English) is a commonly used term in astronomy and in chemistry (in Crystal Field Theory) as well. In both fields, it is used to explain center of mass balance and most of the literature has used the aforementioned spelling. For example, [NASA](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/barycenter/en/) explains the question "What Is a Barycenter?" as:

> We say that planets orbit stars, but that’s not the whole truth. Planets and stars actually orbit around their common center of mass. This common center of mass is called the **barycenter**. Barycenters also help astronomers search for planets beyond our solar system!

In Crystal Field Theory (CFT), electrons in the $\mathrm{d}$-orbitals are repelled to different degrees by the ligands. The degeneracy of the $\mathrm{d}$-orbitals is lifted. The Barycenter is the average energy of the $\mathrm{d}$-orbitals ([Coordination Chemistry II: Theories of Electronic Structure](https://www.chem.uci.edu/%7Elawm/11-20.pdf) and [Crystal Field Theory](https://dunbar.tamu.edu/uploads/courses/Crystal%20field%20theory%20-%20handout.pdf)):

[image: Barycenter]